# fetching data to datatable using ajax source in codeigniter returns empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I' am trying to pass my query result to datatable using ajax source in codeigniter frame i tried this code below but my datatable returns empty im new with this method here's what i did:

controller:

```
public function for_source() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_fname, user_lname FROM user_account WHERE user_priviledge = 'student' LIMIT 20");

        $data = array();

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $data['data'][] = array(
                            'fname' => $row['user_fname'],
                            'lname' => $row['user_lname'],
                            );
        }
       echo json_encode($data);
}
```

this my view :

```
<table id="getWiwit" class="table table-border table-hover table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <td><div style="margin-left: -7px;">user name</div></td>
        <td><div style="margin-left: -7px;">user lname</div></td>
    </tr></thead></table>
```

And here is how i try to put my data to datatable using ajax source

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log(baseUrl+"dashboard.php/acceptedtransaction/for_source/");
var table = $('#getWiwit').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": baseUrl+"dashboard.php/acceptedtransaction/for_source/",
        "type": "POST"
        },
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "fname"},
        { "data": "lname"},
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
});
});
```

help please

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put your url `baseUrl+"dashboard.php/acceptedtransaction/for_source/"` in the browser and see what ajax returns?

Comment: yes and it echoes the json file that i needed, really dont know what i did wrong tsk!

Answer (score 0):

```
  "ajax": {
    "url": "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/acceptedtransaction/for_source/",
    "type": "POST"
    },
```

this URL should be

`"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/acceptedtransaction/for_source/",`

`base_url()/index.php/controller(name)/method(name)`

Comment: Uhmm the baseUrl is actually <?php echo base_url(); ?> i kind of put it in a hidden textbox and call it in my js file but i'll try your method :)